# Streaming the map and modifying it in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I know that once we create the stream off of a collection we should not modify collection while consuming the stream, However not sure if following approach works where I am modifying the entry inside the map and not adding or removing anything from it. Also, is this the right way to stream the map always and consume it ?

```
creepyCategoryStatuses.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
        String creepyBlockResponse = (String) getBlockResponse(entry.getKey());
        if (creepyBlockResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("block")){
            entry.setValue(true); 
         //OR creepyCategoryStatuses(entry.getKey(), true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of modification is no problem as setting the value of an entry is not a *structural modification*. However, it’s worth noting that there are more Java 8 features than the `Stream` API or the `forEach` method:

```
creepyCategoryStatuses.replaceAll((key,value)->
    ((String)getBlockResponse(key)).equalsIgnoreCase("block")||value
);
```

does the job much easier. Note that `||value` will retain the old value if the condition evaluates to `false` as in your original code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such usage of `Map` seems to be legit. Note that in this case you don't need the stream. You can simply use

```
creepyCategoryStatuses.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {...});
```

Comment: Sure, but in above way also, is it ok to modify the entry while intreating over the map?

Answer (score 2):

According to your use-case, you could use [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) here:

```
creepyCategoryStatuses.replaceAll((k, v) -> ((String) getBlockResponse(k)).equalsIgnoreCase("block") ? true : v);
```

I always favor functional paradigms, so I would collect the new data into a new map, but that's a matter of taste.